# Recreate Dynamcis CRM "Filtered Views" for use on SQL server replicated by Scribe RS

Tags: sql-server, database-replication, microsoft-dynamics-crm, scribe

I'm considering moving from CRM 2011 on premise to CRM Online. The major concern for me is the lack of SQL access, but I understand Scribe RS has a replication solution that will keep a copy of the SQL in an external database for reporting.

I spoke with a Scribe representative and they said that the Filtered Views are not replicated. So, if we went this route and wanted that functionality for easier reporting, we would have to rebuild the Filtered Views (and strip out the CRM security portions).

On on-premise, I can view the query that generates each Filtered View, and use that as a starting point to recreate the view externally. However, since there is no SQL access at all on CRM Online, I don't know how I would go about recreating these. Does anyone have experience with this or a suggestion for enabling 3rd party reporting against SQL while using CRM Online?